# Why does this Ruby for loop fail?

Tags: ruby, loops, for-loop

Ok, so I just want to do this Java in Ruby:

```
int [] nums = { 2,4,6,8,10 };
for ( int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++ ){
    nums[i]=nums[i]+100;
}
```

I am doing this:

```
nums = Array[2,4,6,8,10];
hello = nums.length;
for i in 0..hello 
    # puts i
    nums[i]=nums[i] + 100
end
```

Code fails with:

```
qq.rb:5:in `block in <main>': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from qq.rb:3:in `each'
        from qq.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

WHY?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The `puts i` should have told you what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. It was ... instead of ..

Answer (score 6):

You're looping past the end of the array.

`..` is *inclusive*. `0..3` produces the numbers `0, 1, 2, 3`.

You want `...` which does not include the last value in the range. `0...3` produces `0, 1, 2`.

That said, what you *really* want is some idiomatic Ruby:

```
nums = [2,4,6,8,10]
nums.map! { |x| x + 100 } # => [102, 104, 106, 108, 110]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew this was a simple question. Yeah, I was overlooking the final value.

Comment: Idiomatic ruby would be `(2..10).step(2).map &100.method(:+)`.

Comment: @mudasobwa  Err, no. You made the code longer, more complex, and *far* less readable, in the name of cramming as many Ruby methods as you could into one line. That's not how you write idiomatic code.

Comment: It’s always hard to prove anything using _ad hominem_ arguments, but it’s impossible to do it using a lie. My code is 10 symbols _shorter_, try `String#length` on both snippets. Besides that it is “more complex and far less readable” _in your opinion only_, which, basically, is not (and never been) the holy truth. Methods like `step` are used to avoid typos in number lists. `map` is chosen over `map!` because there is no reason to mutate an object (the code that mutates it is misleading and, hence, bad.) Using `Symbol#to_proc` is a first example of idiomatic ruby in any source existing in net.

Comment: I guess readability is subjective, I feel that `map {|x| x +100}` is much more readable than `map &100.method(:+)` but that's because I'm not use to this kind of notation. I agree with @mudasobwa about using `step` and usage of `map` over `map!` though.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 readability matters, but here we were talking about “idiomatic ruby,” I just pointed out that “I like it this way” and “it’s an idiomatic ruby” are not synonyms. And yes, as soon as you are writing ruby code on daily basis `&100.method(:+)` became _more (well, at least not less) readable_ than `{|x| x + 100}`. Unless you are still writing PHP using ruby syntax.